# Why are web miners mostly mining monero?

Tags: mining

There are a lot of web miners - based on WebAssembly. Most of them mine Monero. Is there any special reason for that?

Answer (score 4):

Monero is one of the coins which use an ASIC resistant PoW algorithm (Cryptonight), which means ASICs for it are expensive to make, so CPU have a good shot at mining it, contrary to most other coins, where ASICs and/or GPUs leave CPUs with pretty much no chance.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons I can think of:
addresses aren't traceable and its still (though barely) profitable/mine-able.

Comment: And dou you think, maybe because of its algo? Because it's based on cyrptonight. That's mean; Monero can be mined with CPUs and GPUs?

Comment: I think the 'being profitable' fills that.  3 1070's and a i7 here and its barely profitable at current difficulty.